# Moxy onStop. Сохранение в БД. Вывод Toast-а

Tags: android, moxy

Есть MVP-фрагмент с moxy. Данные сохраняю в БД через rx. Когда приходит успешный колбек из базы, я хочу выводить тост, что всё ок. Типа: getViewState.showToast(s).
Но в onStop происходит уничтожение View(если я правильно понимаю) и соответственно getViewState.showNoast(s) уже не актуально.
Как правильно вывести тост после сохранения в БД?